# How does WannaCrypt detect when someone pays the ransom?

Tags: malware, ransomware, wannacry

It seems they are processing it manually, but how can they verify the payment? WannaCry doesn't provide a unique ransom bitcoin adress for each victim.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Until now, it will be manually operated. But now there is a new path for the money - you got a text message with a request to contact the operator with the private bitcoin wallet address:

[image: https://file.gdatasoftware.com/_processed_/e/b/WannaCryMessage_79096w804h600.jpg]